# What do the colors mean on the Chrome performance CPU graph?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, cpu

Please tell me what the different colors mean, on the CPU graph in Chrome's Performance DevTools.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance) for Chrome indicate that the colors are documented in the 'Summary' tab; but in the latest version of Chrome that does not appear to be accurate. Here is my CPU graph:

[image]

And here is the Summary section:

[image]

Note that the summary section shows most of the CPU activity as yellow ('Scripting'), while the graph shows most of the activity (in the highlighted section) as grey ('System'). Also, the graph has diagonal yellow and green stripes, which are not documented in the Summary section.

Comment: Looks like a bug and I can't reproduce it neither in Chrome stable nor in Canary. As for the hatched fill, it's for tasks [that don't belong to the main thread or frame](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/timeline/TimelineEventOverview.js;l=217).

Comment: Thanks. That's weird you don't repro on Chrome stable - that's what I'm using. Perhaps it is because I'm on a Mac? I'm running version 79.0.3945.88.

Comment: I have also seen this issue quite a few times, and from what I gather the grey bar is shown whenever I visit the profile from lighthouse report's "View Original Trace" button. When I directly record it from Performance tab, it shows in correct yellow color. Let me know if you found the same pattern.